# Handling and converting multiple date formats in a file

Tags: r, date, as.date

i am relatively new to R and have the problem outlined below. Any feedback and help is much appreciated. Many thanks!

I have a 400k lines CSV dataset with contributions from multiple countries, which appear to use different date formats.

In particular, I have four different formats:

(1) dd.mm.yyyy,

(2) excel date numbers,

(3) yyyymmdd

(4) yyyy-mm-dd

I need to convert all different date formats into one so that I can use the date variable to apply additional filters. My preferred target format is (3) yyyymmdd

Converting (4) into (3) is easy but I don't find a way to convert (1) and (2) into (3) as well.
Since four different date formats are in the same file, I think I need to find a way to select all observations with a specific format and then convert only those into format (3) at a time.

For info see the attached screenshot. the relevant dataframe is called dset and the variable is MS_RegistrationDate

[image]

I tried it with the as.Date function as depicted below but this results in all observation receiving the value NA#.

```
dset$MS_RegistrationDate <- as.Date(dset$MS_RegistrationDate, format="%m.%d.%Y")
dset$MS_RegistrationDate <- as.Date(dset$MS_RegistrationDate, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Below is the dput output to replicate a selection of the dataframe

### --
structure(list(Model = c("P 280 B6x2/4NA", "P 280 B6x2*4NB",
"P 320 B6x2*4NA", "P 320 B6x2*4NA", "P 450 B6x2*4NB", "P 280 B6x2NA",
"P 280 B6x2NA", "P 340 B6x2*4NB", "P 280 B6x2NA", "P 280 B6x2NA",
"P 450 B6x2NA", "P 450 B6x2NA", "P 320 B6x2NA", "P 320 B6x2NA",
"P 320 B6x2NA", "P 320 B6x2NA", "P 320 B6x2NA", "P 320 B6x2NA",
"P 320 B6x2NA", "P 500 B6x2*4NB", "P 500 B6x2*4NB"), Make = c("Scania",
"Scania", "Scania", "Scania", "Scania", "Scania", "Scania", "Scania",
"Scania", "Scania", "Scania", "Scania", "Scania", "Scania", "Scania",
"Scania", "Scania", "Scania", "Scania", "Scania", "Scania"),
Manufacturer = c("Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB",
"Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB",
"Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB",
"Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB",
"Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB",
"Scania CV AB", "Scania CV AB"), VehicleGroup = c(9, 9, 9,
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9), VehicleSubgroup = c("9-RD",
"9-RD", "9-RD", "9-RD", "9-LH", "9-RD", "9-RD", "9-RD", "9-RD",
"9-RD", "9-LH", "9-LH", "9-RD", "9-RD", "9-RD", "9-RD", "9-RD",
"9-RD", "9-RD", "9-LH", "9-LH"), MS_RegistrationDate = c("20191129",
"2019-09-26T00:00:00.000", "2019-09-17", "2019-10-08", "30.10.2019",
"2019-09-25", "2019-10-17", "2019-11-21", "2019-10-08", "2019-10-17",
NA, NA, "2019-10-07", "2019-10-07", "2019-10-04", "2019-10-07",
"2019-10-07", "2019-10-07", "2019-10-07", "43766", "43787"
), RegDate_Corrected = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Match = c("Match",
"Match", "Match", "Match", "Match", "Match", "Match", "Match",
"Match", "Match", "OEM_only", "OEM_only", "Match", "Match",
"Match", "Match", "Match", "Match", "Match", "Match", "Match"
), Baseline = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No",
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No",
"No", "No", "No", "No"), VocationalVehicle = c("No", "No",
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No",
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), ZeroEmissionVehicle = c("No",
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No",
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"
), HybridElectricHDV = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_), DualFuelVehicle = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), ExemptedVehicle = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CO2v = c(710.88,
629.9, 683.52, 683.52, 841.48, 682.21, 682.21, 778.85, 682.21,
682.21, 844.79, 844.79, 613.28, 613.28, 679.51, 613.28, 613.28,
613.28, 613.28, 831.71, 831.71), Engine_Displacement_ltr = c(9.3,
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 12.7, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 12.7, 12.7,
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 12.7, 12.7), Engine_FuelType = c("Diesel CI",
"Diesel CI", "Diesel CI", "Diesel CI", "Diesel CI", "Diesel CI",
"Diesel CI", "NG PI", "Diesel CI", "Diesel CI", "Diesel CI",
"Diesel CI", "Diesel CI", "Diesel CI", "Diesel CI", "Diesel CI",
"Diesel CI", "Diesel CI", "Diesel CI", "Diesel CI", "Diesel CI"
), AirDrag_CdxA_range = c("A11", "A9", "A14", "A14", "A11",
"A14", "A14", "A13", "A14", "A14", "A11", "A11", "A9", "A9",
"A13", "A9", "A9", "A9", "A9", "A9", "A9"), WHTC_FuelConsumption_gkwh = c(216,
216, 216, 216, 201, 216, 216, 290, 216, 216, 201, 201, 216,
216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 201, 201), Engine_RatedPower_kw = c(206,
206, 235, 235, 331, 206, 206, 251, 206, 206, 331, 331, 235,
235, 235, 235, 235, 235, 235, 368, 368)), row.names = c(NA,
-21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(mydf)` as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Following the date formates in your example, here is what I came up with:

```
dset <- dset[, c("MS_RegistrationDate", "RegDate_Corrected")]
regdate <- lapply(dset$MS_RegistrationDate, function(datestring) {
    if (!is.na(as.integer(datestring))) {
        if (as.integer(datestring) > 2e7) {
            # This is formatted as 20xxxxxx
           as.Date(datestring, format = "%Y%m%d") 
        } else {
        #This must be an excel date number
            as.Date(as.integer(datestring) , origin="1899-12-30")
        }
    } else if (grepl(pattern = "\\.[0-9]+\\.", x = datestring)) {
        # This has format dd.mm.yyyy
        as.Date(datestring, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
    } else {
        as.Date(datestring)
    }
    })
regdate
```

Although I'm not sure how robust this will be. Are the four date formats that you mention always followed?? There are numerous ways to "creatively" enter dates, that might trip you up...

Comment: HI Micha, thanks for your efforts and your suggestion. Unfortunately, this doesn't work - it actually didn't change the date values at all when I tried to apply the code to the dataset. Did it work when you tried it with the dput dataset? On your question: the total dataset has about 400k lines. I have manually gone through a couple of thousand and the four date formats are those I cam across though I cannot rule out that there are still a few others in the dataset.

Comment: Well, I did not try to change anything in the main data.frame. The code I suggested just creates a new list with POSIX dates. Have a look thru that new list to check that it's working. Then you can update your main data.frame with those values. (i.e. `cbind()` or similar)